# MS teams client custom app uploaded in portal but is not listed in catalog

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-appstudio

I have created a Teams App with the App Studio. When I install it with App Studio everything is working? I am now trying to publish the app to the tenant app store

I have downloaded the app packaged from App Studio and uploaded the package to the Teams admin portal. The package uploads without any errors and the app is shown in the catalog list as a custom app

I have enabled

“Allow third party app”,” Allow any new third party apps… ” “Allow interaction with custom apps” on ”org-wide app” settings

-the global Permission policy I have “Allow all apps” on the three subjects

-the Global Setup Policy I have “Upload custom apps” and ”Allow user pinning” on

But my app does not show in the catalogue in the Teams client

Comment: When you uploaded it in the Apps catalog, did you select "Upload for me or my Teams" or "Upload for [Companyname]"?

Comment: From the admin portal (https://admin.teams.microsoft.com/policies/manage-apps) I selected Team Apps->Manage-Apps>Upload new app. No choice to make

Comment: oh yes, I re-read your question now - I thought you were uploading in the client. Perhaps try that as an option?

Comment: I can upload and use the app directly in the client. But i would like to make it available fore the organisation

Comment: If you want to install the app for the entire organisation, you can try installing it to the private app store. Under upload a custom app option, please choose "Upload for [Your org]"  and add the App. This will then be shown up in the private app store and will be available for everyone in the organisation

Answer (score 0):

After adding and removing the same police, restarting the client multiple times and waiting 48 hours- The app now show up in the catalog